# What's the difference between nexti and stepi in gdb?

Tags: c++, c, debugging, gdb

While debugging an executable using **gdb**, there are two commands which we can use to step through the execution:

- `stepi` and
- `nexti`

What is/are the difference/s between these two and why would anyone choose one over the other?

using help in gdb says:

> stepi:  Step one instruction exactly.
>
> nexti:  Step one instruction, but proceed through subroutine calls.

since we are dealing with instructions and machine code here (the smallest part of a program in execution) I can't figure out what the subroutine calls are.

Comment: If you are on a function call `stepi` will step into the first instruction of the function and stop. If you use `nexti` the function will be executed and it will stop on the instruction after the call. The documentation may be useful: https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Continuing-and-Stepping.html. Subroutine calls are `call` instructions.

Comment: @MichaelPetch It is actually, thanks

Comment: The `nexti` will stop on next instruction after `call` only if the `call` does actually return back (in case of some bug, or intentionally modifying/not using return address, the `call` may never return to the next instruction).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`stepi` is more detailed than `nexti`. if you call `sum()` from `main()` function then doing `stepi` reaches you inside the sum() function, but `nexti` doesn't.

Below is the screenshot when you call `stepi` when you were at **call of sum()** instruction (i.e., `=> 0x08048403 <+40>:    call   0x8048419 <sum>`). The `stepi` instuction routes you inside the `sum()`.

[image]

If you do `nexti` when you were at **call of sum()** instruction (i.e., `=> 0x08048403 <+40>:    call   0x8048419 <sum>`) then it uses the returned value from sum method and goes to the next instruction of main method, screenshot as below.

[image]

**Conclusion**: Use `stepi` if you want to see every machine instructions that happened in your processor. Use `nexti` if you wanna see only the machine instructions executed at the `main()`.

Comment: It is similar to MSVS's step-over and step-into debug commands. "Step over" will never increase call stack (but can reduce if you do step-over at the end of method). Step-into will eagerly jump to the next debuggable line of code, be it "this" or a nested function call.

Answer (score 9):

The difference is how `call` is treated:

- `stepi` dives into `call`
- `nexti` runs `call` but doesn't walk you through its code

Hence here's the semantical rule to remember it better: you are to *step* if you need to *walk through*. Another one could be "*step inside*", thus "next" isn't making sense anyways. ;)